# download ms preconfigured vm to a azure vm and upload

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Can I use my AzureVM to download a preconfigured [VM from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2013/08/02/visual-studio-2013-application-lifecycle-management-virtual-machine-and-hands-on-labs-demo-scripts.aspx), then upload to azure from there? What are the side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you download the image by following the steps in the article you referred to, you can upload it to a storage account using [AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/).